# Use LINQ to populate a single list from two other lists

Tags: c#, linq, list

Right now, I have 2 lists(_pumpOneSpm and _pumpTwoSpm) that are the result of a database query.  Now, I've been using LINQ to populate lists for me to work with for calculations.  Something similar to this:

```
var spmOne = _pumpOneSpm.Where((t, i) => _date[i].Equals(date) &&
            DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0 && 
            DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0).ToList();
```

This has been fine, because I've been pulling data from one list to add specific data into another list.  But now, I need pull data from two lists to add to one list.  I'm curious if there is a way to do this with LINQ, or if I should just iterate through with a for loop?  Here's what I've got with the for loop:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < _pumpOneSpm.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_date[i].Equals(date))
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0)
                    {
                        spmOne.Add(_pumpOneSpm[i]);
                        spmOne.Add(_pumpTwoSpm[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This works, and does what I want.  But I'm just trying to make it a bit more efficient and faster.  I could use two lines similar to the first code block for each list, but that means I'm iterating through twice.  So, to reiterate my question, is it possible to use a LINQ command to pull data from two lists at the same time to populate another list, or should I stick with my for loop?  Thanks for any and all help.

**EDIT**

I failed to mention, that the purpose of the function utilizing these steps is to fine the MAX of _pumpOneSpm & _pumpTwoSpm.  Not the max of each, but the max between them.  Thus initially I was adding them into a single list and just calling spmOne.Max().  But with two LINQ queries like above, I'm running an if statement to compare the two maxes, and then return the greater of the two.  So, technically they don't NEED to be in one list, I just thought it'd be easier to handle if they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the simplest way to do this would be something like this:

```
var resultList = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Note that this will be slightly different than your for loop (the order of the items won't be the same).  It will have all items from one list followed by all items from another, rather than having the first of the first, the first of the second, etc.  If that's important you could still do it with LINQ, but it would take a few extra method calls.

You've mentioned performance; it's worth noting that you aren't going to get significantly better, performance wise, than your `for` loop.  You could get code that's shorter; code that's more readable, and that will perform *about the same*.  There simply isn't room to improve very much more though in terms of runtime speed.

It's also worth noting that you can combine the two method; it's not even a bad idea.  You can use LINQ to filter the two input sequences (using `Where`) and then `foreach` over the results to add them to the list (or use `AddRange`).

```
var query1 = _pumpOneSpm.Where((t, i) => _date[i].Equals(date) &&
            DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0 && 
            DateTime.Compare(_time[i], DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0);
var query2 = ...
List<T> results = new List<T>(query1);
results.AddRange(query2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The concat() would work, as I'm not really worried about the order of the list.  The union() would work as well, since I'm not worried about duplicates either.  I've edited my original post with more information that I failed to add until after reading your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> So, to reiterate my question, is it possible to use a LINQ command to
>   pull data from two lists at the same time to populate another list, or
>   should I stick with my for loop?

Merge the lists:

```
var mergedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

Optionally if you want, then filter:

```
var filtered = mergedList.Where( p => ... filter ... );
```

And for the Max:

```
var max = filtered.Max();
```

NOTE:

As OP says there's no need from order not for not-duplicates so Union will be OK.

Comment: Union is a set operation and will also perform a `Distinct ` in the results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The concat() would work, as I'm not really worried about the order of the list.  The union() would work as well, since I'm not worried about duplicates either.  I've edited my original post with more information that I failed to add until after reading your answer.

Comment: You most likely would want to filter before merging, because the filter is dependent on each element's index.

Comment: @RiskyMartin: Why would I want to filter?  I couldn't care less about duplicates or order, or anything for that matter.  I'm just looking for the highest number between the two lists.

Comment: @Randolf Because the OP is filtering the lists.

Comment: @RiskyMartin The one who replied you is the OP, actually my solution works from him. It's a maximum problem I don't see how filtering is necessary, that's why I explicitly wrote "optionally" on my answer.

Comment: @Kevin You're looking for the highest number that has a corresponding time in another list that must be between `start` and `end`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectMany method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar functionality to the for loop with [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).  [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) then allows you to add multiple items each iteration and then flatten the resulting sequence.

```
spmOne = Enumerable
             .Range(0, _pumpOneSpm.Count)
             .Where(index => _date[index].Equals(date) &&
                     DateTime.Compare(_time[index], DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0 &&
                     DateTime.Compare(_time[index], DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0)
             .SelectMany(index => new [] { _pumpOneSpm[index], _pumpTwoSpm[index] })
             .ToList();
```

Here is the query syntax version:

```
spmOne = (from index in Enumerable.Range(0, _pumpOneSpm.Count)
          where _date[index].Equals(date) &&
                DateTime.Compare(_time[index], DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0 &&
                DateTime.Compare(_time[index], DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0
          from pumpSpm in new [] { _pumpOneSpm[index], _pumpTwoSpm[index] }
          select pumpSpm).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using indexes you can [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) everything together.

```
spmOne = _pumpOneSpm
          .Zip(_pumpTwoSpm, (pump1, pump2) => new { pump1, pump2 } )
          .Zip(_date, (x, pumpDate) => new { x.pump1, x.pump2, date = pumpDate })
          .Zip(_time, (x, time) => new { x.pump1, x.pump2, x.date, time })
          .Where(x => x.date.Equals(date) &&
                      DateTime.Compare(x.time, DateTime.Parse(start)) > 0 &&
                      DateTime.Compare(x.time, DateTime.Parse(end)) < 0)
          .SelectMany(x => new [] { x.pump1, x.pump2 })
          .ToList();
```

There is one small difference in functionality: if any of the sequences are shorter than `_pumpOneSpm`, the resulting sequence will be the length of the shortest sequence, and no exception will be thrown about an index being out of range.