# How can I populate a list of objects from another list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of Test objects:

```
IList<Test> TestFromDatabase ;

public class Test 
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public bool? C { get; set; }
    public bool? R { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I need to make this into a collection of TestResult objects:

```
public class TestResult
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone show me how I can do this with LINQ

Comment: Have you managed to come up with anything yourself?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496512/use-linq-to-populate-a-single-list-from-two-other-lists

Comment: @skyfoot nope, different question, it's about projecting one list into another not concatenating

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Where `tests` is your test list

```
List<Test> tests = PerformTests();
var testresults = tests.Select(x=>new TestResult { TestId = x.TestId, Correct = x.C });
```

I assume that `C` means correct if not you can put there something else. Read more about [Select from linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

It will produce `IEnumerable<TestResult>` so if you want to make it a `List<TestResult>` use [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could do what wudzik suggested.
But if your class has a lot of properties I would use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).
You will need to configure automapper first (add the mappings) there is a guide [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).
I always place this in a bootstrapper class and call this in the global.asax.
For your example it will look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Test, TestResult>();
```

Once the configuration is done you are able to use the following code to create your list:

```
List<Test> tests = PerformTests();
List<TestResult>testresults = tests.Select(t=>Mapper.Map<Test, TestResult>(t)).ToList();
```

Automapper will know which value belongs where if the property names of the two classes are the same. Else you will have to change the configuration a bit.
For your example this will be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Test, TestResult>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Correct, opt => opt.MapFrom(origin => origin.C));
```

This way is very useful when you have a lot of properties to map between the 2 classes.

Hope this will help you.